# How to use more than one function in one event?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use **oninput event** twice but it gives me an error as you can see following.

https://prnt.sc/i6fsr0

```
<input id="Input1" type="text" oninput="myFunction()" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"/>
```

So how to use more than one function in one event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the logic inside the function itself

```
myFunction(){
  //whatever existing logic
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
}
```

or create another function for the logic and use **`;`**

```
<input id="Input1" type="text" oninput="myFunction();mysecondFunction()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the code at the second `oninput` event attribute following the call to `myFunction()` at the first `input` event attribute

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {console.log("myFunction")}
</script>
<input id="Input1" type="text" oninput="myFunction(); this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')"/>
```